# Can I trigger a zookeeper leader election without killing/or restarting the leader?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Is there a way to trigger a zookeeper leader election without restarting the current zookeeper leader? Maybe a 4LTR word?

Comment: That must be one of the most hilariously on-topic questions I have ever seen on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

..while even this request is quite strange, I guess you can try using iptable to block connections to the leader...